# how to skip the strong name verification for delay signed assembilies on Mono and Visual studio 2010(C#4.0)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mono, monodevelop

how to skip the strong name verification for delay signed assembilies on Mono and Visual studio 2010(C#4.0)?

Thanks & Regards,
P.SARAVANAN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass the `-Vr` command-line option to the [strong name tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23.aspx) (`sn.exe`):

```
sn -Vr yourAssembly.dll
```

Be careful though: this should only be done on development machines because of security considerations. Quoth the documentation:

> Use this option only during development. Adding an assembly to the
>   skip verification list creates a security vulnerability. A malicious
>   assembly could use the fully specified assembly name (assembly name,
>   version, culture, and public key token) of the assembly added to the
>   skip verification list to fake its identity. This would allow the
>   malicious assembly to also skip verification.