# How to setup Entity Framework / SQL Server with Mono

Tags: entity-framework, mono

I'm trying to setup a very simple test project to evaluate Mono Entity Framework capabilities. When trying to access data, I get a runtime exception about parsing the model data when using .NET Runtime. When using Mono runtime, a stackoverflow exception is thrown.

**This seems to be an internal mono bug which occurs when compiling the CSDL Schema Version 3 - see [Mono Bugtracker](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6653).**

So my question is:

How do I setup Mono with Entity Framework to work with a Microsoft SQL Server? Since I don't find much information, should this even be possible? Did anyone of you successfully setup a mono solution using EF and came across similar errors?

This is what I have done so far:

- Installed Mono 3.0.1 Beta (latest stable doesn't include `EntityFramework.dll`)
- Setup a [Mono Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13499003/1249506) for Visual Studio
- [Disabled strong name verification for delay signed assembilies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6816381/1249506) for
  `EntityFramework.dll` / `EntityFramework.SQLServer.dll` and added them to the GAC to prevent runtime errors
- Created a simple model + added Code Generation Items
- written code using the model

The code works with Microsoft `EntityFramework.dll` (Version 6, Prerelease). When using the Mono equivalent, it looks like there are problems while parsing the entity model:

Exception message (.NET Runtime):

> *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

Stacktrace (.NET Runtime):

```
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InitStreamInput(Uri baseUri, String baseUriStr, Stream stream, Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteCount, Encoding encoding)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String url, Stream input, XmlNameTable nt)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReader..ctor(Stream input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.SomSchemaSetHelper.AddXmlSchemaToSet(XmlSchemaSet schemaSet, XmlSchemaResource schemaResource, HashSet`1 schemasAlreadyAdded)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.SomSchemaSetHelper.AddXmlSchemaToSet(XmlSchemaSet schemaSet, XmlSchemaResource schemaResource, HashSet`1 schemasAlreadyAdded)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.SomSchemaSetHelper.ComputeSchemaSet(SchemaDataModelOption dataModel)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Result.GetValue()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.SomSchemaSetHelper.GetSchemaSet(SchemaDataModelOption dataModel)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.Parse(XmlReader sourceReader, String sourceLocation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaManager.ParseAndValidate(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption dataModel, AttributeValueNotification providerNotification, AttributeValueNotification providerManifestTokenNotification, ProviderManifestNeeded providerManifestNeeded, IList`1& schemaCollection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest, DbProviderFactory& providerFactory, String& providerManifestToken, Memoizer`2& cachedCTypeFunction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.StoreMetadataEntry.LoadStoreCollection(EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, MetadataArtifactLoader loader)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.LoadItemCollection[T](IItemCollectionLoader`1 itemCollectionLoader, T entry)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetOrCreateStoreAndMappingItemCollections(String cacheKey, MetadataArtifactLoader loader, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Object& entryToken)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.LoadStoreItemCollections(MetadataWorkspace workspace, DbConnection storeConnection, DbConnectionOptions connectionOptions, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, MetadataArtifactLoader artifactLoader)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace(Boolean initializeAllCollections)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.InitializeMetadata(DbConnection newConnection, DbConnection originalConnection, Boolean closeOriginalConnectionOnFailure)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<GetEnumerator>m__2C3()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at EntityFrameworkMono.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Christopher Dresel\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\New\EntityFrameworkMono\EntityFrameworkMono\Program.cs:line 17
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Exception message (Mono Runtime):

> *The requested operation caused a stack overflow.*

Stacktrace (Mono Runtime):

```
  at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaGroupBase.CheckRecursion (Int32 depth, System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler h, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema schema) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaGroupBase.CheckRecursion (Int32 depth, System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler h, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema schema) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaElement.CheckRecursion (Int32 depth, System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler h, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema schema) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaGroupBase.CheckRecursion (Int32 depth, System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler h, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema schema) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaGroupBase.CheckRecursion (Int32 depth, System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler h, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema schema) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaElement.CheckRecursion (Int32 depth, System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler h, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema schema) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaGroupBase.CheckRecursion (Int32 depth, System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler h, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema schema) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaGroupBase.CheckRecursion (Int32 depth, System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler h, System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema schema) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
...
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
CustomerEntities entities = new CustomerEntities();
var count = entities.Customers.Count(); // Exception throws here

Console.WriteLine(count);
Console.ReadKey();
```

`EDMX` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
    <!-- EF Runtime content -->
    <edmx:Runtime>
        <!-- SSDL content -->
        <edmx:StorageModels>
            <Schema Namespace="CustomerModel.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2008" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl">
                <EntityContainer Name="CustomerModelStoreContainer">
                    <EntitySet Name="Customer" EntityType="CustomerModel.Store.Customer" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" />
                </EntityContainer>
                <EntityType Name="Customer">
                    <Key>
                        <PropertyRef Name="CustomerID" />
                    </Key>
                    <Property Name="CustomerID" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
                    <Property Name="CustomerName" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="50" />
                </EntityType>
            </Schema>
        </edmx:StorageModels>
        <!-- CSDL content -->
        <edmx:ConceptualModels>
            <Schema Namespace="CustomerModel" Alias="Self" annotation:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation">
                <EntityContainer Name="CustomerEntities" annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="true">
                    <EntitySet Name="Customers" EntityType="CustomerModel.Customer" />
                </EntityContainer>
                <EntityType Name="Customer">
                    <Key>
                        <PropertyRef Name="CustomerID" />
                    </Key>
                    <Property Name="CustomerID" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
                    <Property Name="CustomerName" Type="String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="50" Unicode="true" FixedLength="false" />
                </EntityType>
            </Schema>
        </edmx:ConceptualModels>
        <!-- C-S mapping content -->
        <edmx:Mappings>
            <Mapping Space="C-S" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs">
                <EntityContainerMapping StorageEntityContainer="CustomerModelStoreContainer" CdmEntityContainer="CustomerEntities">
                    <EntitySetMapping Name="Customers">
                        <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="CustomerModel.Customer">
                            <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Customer">
                                <ScalarProperty Name="CustomerID" ColumnName="CustomerID" />
                                <ScalarProperty Name="CustomerName" ColumnName="CustomerName" />
                            </MappingFragment>
                        </EntityTypeMapping>
                    </EntitySetMapping>
                </EntityContainerMapping>
            </Mapping>
        </edmx:Mappings>
    </edmx:Runtime>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

And finally the connection string I'm using:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CustomerEntities"
         connectionString="metadata=.\CustomerModel.csdl|.\CustomerModel.ssdl|.\CustomerModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=CHRISTOPHERPC\SQLExpress;initial catalog=test;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Did you tried Mono 2.11.3 or newer?

Comment: I tried it out with Mono 3.0.1 Beta from http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html - there is a new Version out now (3.0.2), i will try it again with this version and post my results.

Comment: Same errors when using 3.0.2...

Comment: The bug is in EF - see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 5):

Dresel, misleading as my reputation may be on this site, I can safely say that using the EntityFramework with mono is not the recommended approach at this time. Although it is technically "supported", the majority of the library is non functional at best. After spending about a month digging as far as I could go, I was unable to peg the possibility of making a fully functioning site above %20. I instead used NHibernate and have been thrilled with the results. And recommend doing the same until the base has solidified further for the EF Mono project. [Nhibernate Example (using MySQL, MSSQL supported)](http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2011/05/02/mono-nhibernate-mysql-a-complete-example/)

I hope this helps at least a little bit as it's only my sincere thought. Good luck on whatever you choose to do, I know this MS Opensource move can get very "roadblocky"

Comment: just curious - when you say "non-functional library", are you talking about the latest mono versions (3.x)?

Comment: For my team and myself running Ubuntu and all of the latest software as of the end of December. They're libraries do compile in windows, but some things that were needed were not supported at that time.

Comment: But you were able to get EF running? As you read in my post, im not even able to do that - and there are no ressources (at least I found none) on this topic either. So if you have any hint about how that could be done, or can tell me what things I'm missing, I would very appreciate that.

Comment: I did eventually get a simple CRUD page working on and off, I no longer have the project or I would send it to you. It was VERY inconsistent however. Down to the point that if one thing executed to quickly nothing would function.

Comment: May I asked you which development setup did you used? VS / MonoDevelop - Windows / Linux / Mac?

Comment: I first tried using Windows, the most success we had was using MySQL/Windows actually I do believe. We then gave OpenSuse a shot due to it shipping with Mono (Novelle actually contributes/contributed to the Mono Project). Shockingly however, Ubuntu was the winner for us. Due to it's larger backing, (I personally don't care for it) there was much more support on the topic. Still, no dice. I was pointed in the direction of NHibernate, made a test project in under 20 minutes and never looked back. I'd choose Ubuntu again when diving into the EF/Mono foray again for sure though.

Comment: @Chazt3n may I know if now, 1 year later, you have had any further exposure to EF in Mono, and if yes, is your opinion it still is a non-functional library?

Comment: Although I haven't personally used EF with mono again, however I would consider it functional now. EF6 is fully open source/ supported. If you were to use MySQL, my understanding is that you would need a commercial connector. Please let me know if I can help with any other specific instances. I may need to revisit/delete this question. EDIT 2: I would still recommend NHibernate %100 as it has about an 8 year head start.