# NullReferenceException with EF6 on Mono 3.0.3

Tags: entity-framework, mono, entity-framework-6

I am trying to migrate existing Entity Framework project to Mono and found a strange bug: when request being executed and EF loads model schema it throws under Mono despite that under .Net with EF6 Alpha 2 it works. An exception is following:

```
at System.Xml.XmlReader.CalcBufferSize(Stream input)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InitStreamInput(Uri baseUri, String baseUriStr, Stream stream, Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteCount, Encoding encoding)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String url, Stream input, XmlNameTable nt)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReader..ctor(Stream input)
at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.Read(Stream stream, ValidationEventHandler validationEventHandler)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.SomSchemaSetHelper.AddXmlSchemaToSet(XmlSchemaSet schemaSet, XmlSchemaResource schemaResource, HashSet`1 schemasAlreadyAdded)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.SomSchemaSetHelper.AddXmlSchemaToSet(XmlSchemaSet schemaSet, XmlSchemaResource schemaResource, HashSet`1 schemasAlreadyAdded)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.SomSchemaSetHelper.ComputeSchemaSet(SchemaDataModelOption dataModel)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.<Evaluate>c__AnonStorey106.<>m__100()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Result.GetValue()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.SomSchemaSetHelper.GetSchemaSet(SchemaDataModelOption dataModel)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.CreateXmlReaderSettings()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.Parse(XmlReader sourceReader, String sourceLocation)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaManager.ParseAndValidate(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption dataModel, AttributeValueNotification providerNotification, AttributeValueNotification providerManifestTokenNotification, ProviderManifestNeeded providerManifestNeeded, IList`1& schemaCollection)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, Boolean throwOnError)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest, DbProviderFactory& providerFactory, String& providerManifestToken, Memoizer`2& cachedCTypeFunction)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.StoreMetadataEntry.LoadStoreCollection(EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, MetadataArtifactLoader loader)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.StoreItemCollectionLoader.LoadItemCollection(StoreMetadataEntry entry)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.LoadItemCollection[T](IItemCollectionLoader`1 itemCollectionLoader, T entry)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetOrCreateStoreAndMappingItemCollections(String cacheKey, MetadataArtifactLoader loader, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Object& entryToken)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.LoadStoreItemCollections(MetadataWorkspace workspace, DbConnection storeConnection, DbConnectionOptions connectionOptions, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, MetadataArtifactLoader artifactLoader)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace(Boolean initializeAllCollections)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.InitializeMetadata(DbConnection newConnection, DbConnection originalConnection, Boolean closeOriginalConnectionOnFailure)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<GetEnumerator>m__2C3()
at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction`1>m__29A[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
```

I guess it cannot load metadata or something like that, at least deapest lines looks like known behaviour of XmlDocument and XmlSchema when they do not check that input stream is null. I tried to use metadata files instead of embedded resources, but it did not help.

I will try to digg into sources, but it would be really helpful if someone already have idea what is going on.

Comment: Interesting, a search for files "CalcBufferSize" in mono sources gives no results

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to setup Entity Framework / SQL Server with Mono](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624065/how-to-setup-entity-framework-sql-server-with-mono)

Comment: Not strictly a duplicate, but the answer to this question ("it's a bug") is part of the other question.

Comment: Since this is a while ago, did you have any success on your Mono / EF configuration?

Comment: Yes, finally after two weeks of communication with Xamarin I forced that solution to work with Mono, Database First, Postgres, DevArt provider and original .Net assembly of EF (because at that time Mono had early EF 6 Alpha 1 sources not supported by provider). Main problems with Xml model parsing were fixed by Atsushi Eno. Bit later Marek Safar merged fresh sources of EF into Mono, but honestly I still not tested it. Xamarin is very responsive and responsible, so I thing that life on the planet of Mono exists :)

Answer (score 0):

You are running quite unusual configuration, EF compiled by Mono and System.XML from .NET Framework. This itself should work if System.XML can deal with the location of your schema but it's not common configuration.

I'd check how is the schema embedded into your assembly and whether is using same namespace.

Comment: You are right, it looks like it was .Net version of System.XML, but there are problems with both versions. I`m looking for workaround and will post here if I will find it.